# How did the Straw Hat crew become stronger in Enies Lobby?

Tags: one-piece

In Enies Lobby, everyone looks like they've suddenly become stronger (and have
new techniques). Luffy, learned how to pump his blood and his bone. Sanji, learned how to burn his foot. Nami, learned to do Fatamorgana. Zoro with his Asura?

Which part in the story that tells how they got such power?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an interesting answer to a similar question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/2c5chz/question_about_luffy_zoro_and_sanji_at_enies_lobby/):

> **The main idea behind their power jump is that when the Strawhats first fought CP9, they were largely confused and unsure.** All they wanted to do was get Robin back, and only attacked CP9 after they got in their way. Note that in the Galley-La mansion, Luffy tried to reason with Robin first, and only attacked Lucci twice: once to defend Paulie and afterwards while Robin was exiting the room. Zoro attacked Kaku only after Robin was leaving as well. It's the same with Sanji on the sea train; when he kicked Blueno, Sogeking was holding Robin. Sanji wasn't trying to beat Blueno, only make him let go of the kart.
>   **Does that mean the three of them weren't going all out? In a sense, you could argue that: Why go all out on an opponent you don't even need to defeat? Would defeating them have gotten Robin back? Absolutely. But the Strawhats typically avoid conflict unless necessary; as evident by the fact that Luffy only states he'll kick someone's ass after he has a reason too.**
>   I always saw two reasons behind the power jump. **First, CP9 was the strongest group they had ever faced, and forced Luffy, Zoro, and Sanji to become stronger, which I'm sure definitely helped. However, the second reason is that, in order to get Robin back, they had to go through CP9.** They couldn't talk to her like in the mansion, nor could they have kicked Blueno off the kart like on the train. Without defeating CP9, they couldn't get Robin back, and so they put everything they had into their battles because there was no other alternative.

A canonical reference is this:

[image]

**Another point to be noted is that Luffy's new learned techniques of Gear Second and Gear Third make sense because he had been working on new techniques/moves after fighting Aokiji the first time, and Zoro's Asura can also be explained on the basis of the immense training he undergoes on a daily routine. Nami's learned techniques are mostly just various scientific uses of the [perfected Clima Tact](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Art_of_Weather/Perfect_Clima-Tact) that she was given by Usopp.**

> After the events in Skypiea, Usopp upgraded the Clima-Tact into the Perfect Clima-Tact, which was first introduced when Nami and crew were trying to catch up to the Puffing Tom with the [Rocket Man](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Rocket_Man). **With a better knowledge of Nami's preferences and a handful of Dials to spare, he changed the Clima-Tact from a party toy with a few combat capabilities into lethal weapon capable of amazing weather powers that only Nami could unleash.** With this, Nami became fully capable of fighting on her own, and just as superhumanly powerful, in a sense, as any other crew member.

Comment: As a side comment on that in the anime luffy even states it that before they were confused and unsure but now they have a goal and will beat them.

Comment: Also I seem to remember that Luffy said that he got the idea for Gear 2nd after riding on the "rocket man", which was powered by steam.

Comment: @jphager2 I don't remember seeing/reading anything of the sort. Can you point me to the source if you remember?

Comment: @Ashish Gupta. So I am looking for it now. So far all I found is that ch. 376, Luffy says that he has a new technique that he wants to try out. It seems that Luffy doesn't say it but rather Blueno.  In ch. 388, Blueno asks Luffy if he is trying to imitate a steam engine. So it seems that I remembered it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the point that they got stronger simply because they had too, they had no alternative.
It's ridiculous the way luffy gets stronger. It's ridiculous and bright at the same time. I remember when Luffy fought Arlong's pet, Mohmoo, he invented a technique based on Genzo's small windmill. Later on Alabasta, he improvised with misu no luffy, in which he covered himself in water to be able to hit Sir Crocodile. On Ennies Lobby he inspired himself in a Steam Engine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Douglas. We look for factual answers that can be supported with links to external websites. Can you please include some thinks to the sources you used to come to this answer. Any opinions should be posted in comments. Additionally, Please see [how to write a good question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for details on what we expect in an answer.